# Vue.js DOM not updating when trying to clear dictionary

Tags: vue.js

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/78310/)

I have a dictionary that is being rendered by a v-for loop, and I want to set the dictionary to a blank dictionary. I've tried using this.dict = {} and using Vue.delete on all keys, and these update the dictionary in the console but the DOM is not re-rendered. How can I clear this dictionary so that it is re-rendered in the DOM.

html

```
<ol>
  <li v-for="item in Object.keys(todos)">
    <label>{{item}}:{{todos[item]}}</label>
  </li>
</ol>
<button v-on:click = "reset()">reset</button>
```

js

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: {"a" : "b"}
  },
  methods: {
    reset: function(){
      this.todos = {};
      console.log(this.todos);
      Vue.delete(todos, "a");
      Vue.set(todos, "a", "");
    }.bind(this)
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't `bind` the reset method. http://jsfiddle.net/d17298fw/

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the component like this:

```
   new Vue({
     el: "#app",
     data: {
            todos: {"a" : "b"}
           },
     methods: {
       reset(){
              this.todos = {};
              console.log(this.todos);
              Vue.delete(todos, "a");
              Vue.set(todos, "a", "");
             }
     }
  })
```